# dropdown-menu disappear when click inside it

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

To implement Login, i used a dropdown control It's a simple dropdown placed to the right of the navbar made up of the input username and password fields and a button to send the data.
the HTML code is:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:20px">
    <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" id="UtenteLogin">Utente:</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav navbar-nav hidden" id="Logoutmenu">LogOut</a></li>
    <li class="nav navbar-nav show" id="Loginmenu">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-lr animated slideInRight" role="menu">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3><b>Log In</b></h3>
                </div>
                <form id="ajax-login-form" method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            @*<div class="col-xs-7">
                                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" name="remember" id="remember">
                                <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                            </div>*@
                            <div class="col-xs-5 pull-right">
                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Log In">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="hide" name="token" id="token" value="a465a2791ae0bae853cf4bf485dbe1b6">
                </form>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

the problem is that when I click on it, it disappears!
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have some Javascript to go with that HTML?

Comment: What is disappearing? clicking on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong class on **li** element

```
 <li class="nav navbar-nav show" id="Loginmenu">
```

in this part of html

I fixed it and it is working right now

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:20px">
  <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" id="UtenteLogin">Utente:</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav navbar-nav hidden" id="Logoutmenu">LogOut</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown" id="Loginmenu">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-lr animated slideInRight" role="menu">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h3><b>Log In</b></h3>
        </div>
        <form id="ajax-login-form" method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" autocomplete="off">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              @*
              <div class="col-xs-7">
                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" name="remember" id="remember">
                <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
              </div>*@
              <div class="col-xs-5 pull-right">
                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Log In">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" class="hide" name="token" id="token" value="a465a2791ae0bae853cf4bf485dbe1b6">
        </form>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

thses samples will help you to understand how to implement it [link1](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp)

[Link2](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_login&stacked=h)

Comment: ok..but if i click on Login Text (<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <span class="caret"></span></a>), disappear anyway (in my case or in 'www.w3schools.com' example, click near 'forgot password'). Is There a solution for this last problem?

Comment: for w3shools sample if you move **forget password link** inside the **form** element this issue won't happen but for your case you don't have forget password it disappear in your case only when you click login button because it is submit button so it submit the whole form                                                                  `<input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Log In">`  you can change its type to not submit `type="button"`

Comment: I did not explain myself. The submit button is okay ... I want to prevent it from disappearing when I click on the title Login Text (<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <span class="caret"></span></a>).

Comment: you mean the login button not a appear at all or part of it appear @Marco

Comment: when I click on the text 'Log In' (not the submit but the titleinside <a>), the form disappears. I want to avoid it.

Comment: actually I run it in my side it is working fine may be you have different version can you post it on any online js fiddler

Comment: Ok. I solved. I moved the word 'Log In' into the form and everything works fine.